# Possible to use the new Razor syntax

Tags: 2010

Is it possible to make SP2010 run .net 4 and also use the new Razor syntax that is introduced with asp.net mvc3 ?

Larsi

Comment: SP2010 will only run in .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Possible for Razor, but a pain. Have to stick to .NET 3.5 though.
Find an example here: http://tqcblog.com/2011/01/22/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-views-in-sharepoint/